# Why when I ssh into one server it shows bash and the other have my username?

Tags: bash, command-line, rhel

So at work I have two web servers that I am able to `ssh` into.

Both are RHEL 6.5

When I log into one, it shows this:

```
[username@ldvweb01 /]$
```

When I log into the other one it shows:

```
-bash-4.1$
```

I find it way more elegant when it shows the first one. How do I switch between the two? Can someone explain this to me?

---

After running this `echo $PS1` these are the results

```
-bash-4.1$ echo $PS1
\s-\v\$
```

and

```
[appadmin@ldvcatweb01 /]$ echo $PS1
[\u@\h \W]\$
```

---

After checking for the differences between both home directories. I found that there was no `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` in the home directory.

So I copied the ones from the previous server.

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

and

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions
```

I am guess that it just pulls the default bash settings from `/etc`

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: your home folder may not be identical. check how `.bashrc` `.bash_profile` scripts are handle on each server

Comment: You are asking about a bash prompt which you can setup with setting PS1: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-PS1 and http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Printing-a-Prompt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bash prompt is configured by the `PS1` environment variable.  You can get the  prompt you desire by adding

```
export PS1="[\u@\h \W]\$ "
```

to your `.bashrc` file (located in your user's home directory).

The full list of special characters that you can use for your prompt can be found in the [official Bash documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Printing-a-Prompt).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your login shell on both machines is bash, it's the `PS1` environment variable that is different. This variable dictates the format of your prompt.

You can use `echo $PS1` to see what `PS1` is set to on the first machine, then use `export PS1=...` to set it to the same value on the second machine. To make this change permanent, you should add the `export` command to your `.bashrc` file (or possibly your `.profile` file, which is sourced by login shells - it depends on your configuration.)

**Edit:** According to your comment, what you need to do to get the exact same prompt on your second machine as on your first machine, is the command

```
export PS1="[\u@\h \W]\$"
```

You can make it permanent as already explained.

Answer (score 3):

Your home folder may not be identical on each system. You can check `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` scripts are handle on each server. for the prompt you need to include `export PS1="\u@\h \w> "` in your bash login script (.bash_profile)

You may want to have your home directory on a NFS mount to be able to see similar environment on each system.

Comment: This helped me a lot! Those files didn't exist! Thanks!